# Current regulator for 12 V DC system

Tags: voltage-regulator, amperage

I'm looking into using a Noco NLP30 battery for a car I'm building.
As far a specs go the battery should be fine for starting and maintaining accessories.
However, the battery can only handle 24 amps input before the module shuts the battery off.
My alternator has a max output of 120 amps.
Obviously the alternator will be taking most of the load while running and the battery should not exceed 24 amps after its been running. My concern is after the initial start and voltage drop it likely will exceed the 24 amps into the battery.

I'm looking to see if there's some kind of current regulator to cap the input amperage to below 24 amps.

Comment: isn't the battery designed as a drop-in replacement for a lead-acid automotive battery?

Comment: I 'could' recommend using a DC-DC 12V automotive charger. They can output ~10A. But they are used to charge battery from another battery, so you would need another buffer-like battery. Also the charging current depends on voltage of battery - the lower it is, the higher the current.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building the car, look at alternator voltage regulators not current regulators. That 24A spec you saw is the batteries max charging current but the battery is actually specified to deliver 700 Amps peak current, meaning it can handle short bursts of 700 amps. So I don't think you need to worry about exceeding the 24 amp limit in any direction. The voltage regulator will keep a steady 12-14 volts across the battery ensuring that the battery's own internal resistance (usually charge-dependent) will be enough to safely limit the current and not exceed spec.

Comment: i called and spoke with tech from noco, they specifically said that the battery will shut down with anything over 24 amp input.

Comment: Right but you're not going to be at risk of approaching 24 amps nominal. Just supply them with the right voltage. Datasheet says they like 14.6V for charging. I would build your electrical system the same way you normally would then use an external voltage regulator like this one -> [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LfI1z9wGRA) You can dial in exactly 14.6 with that and all will be good. Datasheet -> [link](https://no.co/media/nocodownloads/format/n/l/nlp30_data_sheet_9.24.21_2.pdf) NLP30 in a freight line ambulance -> [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-AQbPCdtfE&t=98s).